# ftp mget not working when used in a script

Tags: unix, batch-file, ftp

I am trying to get a number of files from a Unix machine using an MS DOS ftp script (Windows 7). I am new to this so I have been trying to modify an on-line example. The code is as follows:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

REM ##################################
REM Change these parameters
set FTP_HOST=host
set FTP_USER=user
set FTP_REMOTE_DIR=/users/myAcc/logFiles
set FTP_REMOTE_FILE=*.log
set FTP_LOCAL_DIR=C:\Temp
set FTP_TRANSFER_MODE=ascii
REM ##################################
set FTP_PASSWD=password

set SCRIPT_FILE=%TEMP%\ftp.txt
(
    echo %FTP_USER%
    echo %FTP_PASSWD%
    echo %FTP_TRANSFER_MODE%
    echo lcd %FTP_LOCAL_DIR%
    echo cd  %FTP_REMOTE_DIR%
    echo prompt
    echo mget %FTP_REMOTE_FILE%
) > %SCRIPT_FILE%

ftp -s:%SCRIPT_FILE% %FTP_HOST%
del %SCRIPT_FILE%

ENDLOCAL
```

However, when I run this the `mget` command fails and the following output is given:

Note: the output from the rest of the script shows that all of the previous steps are working as expected. I have even added `ls` commands to verify the script is in the correct directory.

```
...
ftp> mget *.log
200 Type set to A; form set to N.
mget logFile1_SystemOut_22-01-13.log? mget logFile2_SystemOut_22-01-13.log? mget 
logFile3_SystemOut_22-01-13.log? ftp>
```

I have run through this manually repeating the exact same steps and it works fine - no problems and the files are successfully transferred to the C:\Temp directory.

I have checked numerous forums and other websites and I can't see any reason why it should behave like this. Any pointers as to why this doesn't work in the script would be great!

Thanks

Comment: are you sure the prompt command executed correctly?

Comment: you're using `-s` options and `%var%` vars, not $var for unix? aSome `ftp` clients have cmd line options to turn off the prompt, which is as MarcB hints, is the high probablity source of your problem. Good question, good script! Good luck.

Comment: @Mark - Yea, the prompt command appears to get executed because I don't get the option to confirm the download.
@shelter I would assume that since the script is being run via a Windows DOS terminal that the variables should be of the form `%var%` and not `$var`
I should have noted that the whole output for the mget commands is shown at once without being given a choice to confirm each file.

Answer (score 1):

The usual option for turning off the prompt generated by ftp mget is

```
ftp -i
```

By default ftp waits with a prompt for each file found by the `mget "wildcard"` string you generate in your script.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I tried using the `ftp -i` command you mentioned and it doesn't work either.  I should have noted in the original post that the whole output for the `mget` commands is shown at once without being given a choice to confirm each file. This strikes me as slightly odd as it is obviously able to find the file as it lists them but the `mget` command itself is not executed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I call [ftp](/questions/tagged/ftp) scripts on Windows like this:

```
ftp -i -s:%SCRIPT_FILE% %FTP_HOST%
```

This because `ftp -si:%SCRIPT_FILE% %FTP_HOST%` doesn't work.

I guess it's the same on [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) - the switches have to be separated.

Answer (score 0):

`ftp -i` worked for me.

Change `ftp -s:%SCRIPT_FILE% %FTP_HOST%` for `ftp -si:%SCRIPT_FILE% %FTP_HOST%` in your script as @jim mcnamara suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`ftp -i -s:%SCRIPT_FILE% %FTP_HOST%` worked for me, too.

another option is to switch prompt in the ftp script before you invoke mget (that you do) and i've also read `mget -i` somewhere.

but note: `prompt` in the ftp script switches the prompt back on if it had been off before. so use either `ftp -i` OR `prompt`, but not both!

you can check if your script works otherwise by echoing a few `y`'s in the ftp script after mget, so it answers yes to the prompts as they come up.